# Get most recent file in a directory on Linux

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

Looking for a command that will return the single most recent file in a directory.

Not seeing a limit parameter to `ls`...

Comment: `watch -n1 'ls -Art  | tail -n 1'` - shows the very last files

Comment: Most answers here parse the output of `ls` or use `find` without `-print0` which is problematic for handling annoying file-names. Always useful to mention: [BashFAQ099](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/099) which gives a POSIX answer to this problem

Comment: Also very useful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29899/how-can-i-use-find-and-sort-the-results-by-mtime

Comment: newer but similar question is here: [Bash script to find and display oldest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097167/bash-script-to-find-and-display-oldest-file/64156260)

Comment: @kvantour , I had the same concern. However, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38996701/6505499) from @Stephane_Chazelas uses `-printf` with `\0` at the end of the output - basically making it a formatted `-print0`. For me, it's a lot easier - or at least more elegant - to put the newest (or oldest) filename into a string using what @Stephane_Chazelas shared rather than using [BashFAQ/099](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/099). Any comments on this are welcome ... in the chat. (P.S. BashFAQ/099 is a _great_ answer and something that I think everyone should know about, by the way.)

Answer (score 460, accepted):

```
ls -Art | tail -n 1
```

This will return the latest modified file or directory. Not very elegant, but it works.

Used flags:

`-A` list all files except `.` and `..`

`-r` reverse order while sorting

`-t` sort by time, newest first

Comment: using ls -Artls you can also view the file date.

Comment: A minor issue: This version pipes all the output of `ls` to `tail`, then prints only the LAST line. IMHO it is better to sort in ascending order and use `head` instead, as `chaos` suggested. After printing the first line head quits, so sending the next line (actually next block) will rise a SIGPIPE and `ls` will quit as well.

Comment: @TrueY I quite agree. Chaos' answer is better for efficiency.

Comment: Note that this solution includes directories as well as files. This could be a good thing or a bad thing; it depends on what the individual user wants.  The reason I bring this up is that the original question says "file".

Comment: @dmckee you should either remove -r from command or change tail to head :D

Comment: For those who just want the filename: $(ls -rt | tail -n 1)

Comment: I think that the intended benefit of using tail instead of head may be to exclude the inclusion of the line describing total returned by the ls.

Comment: Works on Mac :)

Comment: This lists the most recent file of a folder not the most recent file of a directory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How would one siphon this into another command? For example, how could you use `rm -rf` to remove the latest file spat out by the command you give?

Comment: how to open the file in addition to show its name? Thanks!

Answer (score 274):

```
ls -t | head -n1
```

This command actually gives the latest modified file or directory in the current working directory.

Comment: Equivalent to mine, and possibly more efficient, too.

Comment: doesn't quite work for me since i echo out some info in my ls first, but i get the usage, thanks!

Comment: This lists the files based on the last time the meta information was changed. See the man page for `ls`.

Comment: dmckee solution is better because you can add also the date stamp using "ls -Artls | tail -n 1"

Comment: @Josir This can be modified to include the datestamp with `ls -tl | head -n 1`, and it doesn't have to push the whole table through the pipe the way mine does.

Comment: @ack if your `ls` outputs extraneous stuff, all sorts of scripts are going to break. Standard `ls` is smart enough to know when it's writing to a pipe rather than a terminal, and turns off things like columns and colours.

Comment: Is there a way to filter by file extension, for example PNG?

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ `ls -t *.png | head -n1`

Comment: This returns a folder if it's the latest modified, use:
`ls -Art | head -n1` if you specifically want the latest modified file

Comment: @achasinh Replace `head` with `tail`. And ideally include `--group-directories-first` also.

Comment: @achasinh how can `--reverse` `modification time` return latest file? :)

Answer (score 184):

This is a recursive version (i.e. it finds the most recently updated file in a certain directory or any of its subdirectory)

```
find /dir/path -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f 2- | tail -n 1
```

Brief layman explanation of command line:

- `find /dir/path -type f` finds all the files in the directory

  - `-printf "%T@ %p\n"` prints a line for each file where `%T@` is the float seconds since 1970 epoch and `%p` is the filename path and `\n` is the new line character
  - for more info see `man find`
- `|` is a shell `pipe` (see `man bash` section on `Pipelines`)
- `sort -n` means to sort on the first column and to treat the token as numerical instead of lexicographic (see `man sort`)
- `cut -d' ' -f 2-` means to split each line using the   character and then to print all tokens starting at the second token (see `man cut`)

  - NOTE: `-f 2` would print only the second token
- `tail -n 1` means to print the last line (see `man tail`)

Comment: Here's a solution for Mac: `find $DIR -type f -exec stat -lt "%Y-%m-%d" {} \+ | cut -d' ' -f6- | sort -n | tail -1`

Comment: Problem is the cut command truncates paths with spaces instead of -f 2 use -f2- to return fields 2 to the end of the line

Comment: As in the suggestion by chaos, if you reverse the sort by using `sort -nr`, you can use `head -n 1` instead of `tail -n 1` and improve efficiency slightly. (Although if you're sorting a recursive find, getting the first or last line won't be the slow part.)

Comment: Very useful! I find it more friendly if piped to ls though: `find ./ -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" -ls | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f 2- | tail -n 1 |  xargs -r ls -lah`

Comment: @user's Mac version only sorts/displays date, not time. Here's a fixed version: `find $DIR -type f -exec stat -lt "%F %T" {} \+ | cut -d' ' -f6- | sort -n | tail -1`

Comment: IMO this is the most useful of all the answers here. Thank you!

Comment: The `sort`, `cut`, and `tail` combination can be replaced with a single `awk` looking for the maximum number -- then outputting the second field at the end. An O(n) operation rather than O(n*ln(n)), that `sort` requires: `awk '$1 > latest { latest = $1; p = $2 } END { print p }'`

Comment: it probably goes without saying, but imho `find` is in many ways (for this specific question) preferable to `ls`, and can be used instead of `ls` in many of the other answers provided. But in this case, one would prefer *not* to have a recursive file listing. So to just list files in the current directory, add in `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ....` etc etc

Comment: This breaks on filenames that include `\n`.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77910532/5353461) is a safe version.

Answer (score 32):

A note about reliability:

Since the newline character is as valid as any in a file name, any solution that relies on *lines* like the `head`/`tail` based ones are flawed.

With GNU `ls`, another option is to use the `--quoting-style=shell-always` option and a `bash` array:

```
eval "files=($(ls -t --quoting-style=shell-always))"
((${#files[@]} > 0)) && printf '%s\n' "${files[0]}"
```

(add the `-A` option to `ls` if you also want to consider hidden files).

If you want to limit to regular files (disregard directories, fifos, devices, symlinks, sockets...), you'd need to resort to GNU `find`.

With bash 4.4 or newer (for `readarray -d`) and GNU coreutils 8.25 or newer (for `cut -z`):

```
readarray -t -d '' files < <(
  LC_ALL=C find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name '.*' -printf '%T@/%f\0' |
  sort -rzn | cut -zd/ -f2)

((${#files[@]} > 0)) && printf '%s\n' "${files[0]}"
```

Or recursively:

```
readarray -t -d '' files < <(
  LC_ALL=C find . -name . -o -name '.*' -prune -o -type f -printf '%T@%p\0' |
  sort -rzn | cut -zd/ -f2-)
```

Best here would be to use `zsh` and its glob qualifiers instead of `bash` to avoid all this hassle:

Newest regular file in the current directory:

```
printf '%s\n' *(.om[1])
```

Including hidden ones:

```
printf '%s\n' *(D.om[1])
```

Second newest:

```
printf '%s\n' *(.om[2])
```

Check file age after symlink resolution:

```
printf '%s\n' *(-.om[1])
```

Recursively:

```
printf '%s\n' **/*(.om[1])
```

Also, with the completion system (`compinit` and co) enabled, <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> becomes a completer that expands to the newest file.

So:

```
vi Ctrl+Xm
```

Would make you edit the newest file (you also get a chance to see which it before you press <kbd>Return</kbd>).

```
vi Alt+2Ctrl+Xm
```

For the second-newest file.

```
vi *.cCtrl+Xm
```

for the newest `c` file.

```
vi *(.)Ctrl+Xm
```

for the newest *regular* file (not directory, nor fifo/device...), and so on.

Comment: Thanks for `zsh` tips. Could you provide a link to more details about this in zsh docs ?

Comment: @freezed, see `info zsh qualifiers`

Comment: Thanks @Stephane Chazelas

Comment: I like `*(.om[1])`, but I usually want to find the newest file in a set of folders, ie. `/path/to/folders*/*(.om[1])`, which unfortunately only returns the newest file in all matched folders. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/552103/limiting-the-scope-of-glob-qualifiers-in-zsh on how to accomplish it over multiple folders.

Comment: I always want to see the newest created file instead os newest modified file. so: `printf '%s\n' **/*(.oc[1])`

Comment: @SergioAraujo, `c` like `find`'s `-ctime` is for the *inode change time* which has nothing to do with the *creation* time. The `mtime` can be seen as the creation time of the file's contents (as those are never created in one go). Some systems and filesystems record a *birth*/*creation* time which is the time a file's inode spawns (possibly *again*) into existence, but there's no portable API to retrieve that, and zsh has no corresponding sorting qualifier yet. But that particular time is not particularly useful. See [When was file created](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/119699)

Comment: Excellent work on the recognition that not all filenames are _nice_. This is the robust version I was looking for (since I couldn't figure out how to use `-print0` and `printf`. Your tip made things quite a bit more elegant than the also-robust [BashFAQ/099](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/099) (which might get merged with [BashFAQ/003](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003)).

Comment: The `bash` answer is great, too.

Comment: is the `! -name '.*'` in your bash 4.4 solution negating the name pattern...ah.. it's saying "ignore the dot files".

Answer (score 11):

I use:

`ls -ABrt1 --group-directories-first | tail -n1`

It gives me just the file name, excluding folders.

Comment: unless a directory has only directories

Answer (score 10):

I like  `echo *(om[1])` (`zsh` syntax) as that just gives the file name and doesn't invoke any other command.

Comment: Works fine if you're using zsh. Are you not using zsh? I think bash is the default in Ubuntu; you can install zsh, or you can find an equivalent command for bash.

Comment: The command is "echo"; it just evaluates its parameters and sends them to standard output. In this case, the glob qualifier "om[1]" has "o", which means order the matching files by "m", which is modified time. And from that ordered list, take [1], which is the first file.  You can read about glob qualifiers: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers

Answer (score 9):

The find / sort solution works great until the number of files gets really large (like an entire file system).  Use awk instead to just keep track of the most recent file:

```
find $DIR -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" | 
awk '
BEGIN { recent = 0; file = "" }
{
if ($1 > recent)
   {
   recent = $1;
   file = $0;
   }
}
END { print file; }' |
sed 's/^[0-9]*\.[0-9]* //'
```

Comment: This runs very fast and accurately even on large directories or file systems. Very elegant and efficient solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

`ls -lAtr | tail -1`

The other solutions do not include files that start with `'.'`.

This command will also include `'.'` and `'..'`, which may or may not be what you want:

`ls -latr | tail -1`

Comment: Will this one return "."  if the directory has been modified more recently than any file contained (say by a deletion)? Maybe that is the desired behavior, maybe not. But you're right either way.

Answer (score 7):

Shorted variant based on dmckee's answer:

```
ls -t | head -1
```

Comment: but the `-1` syntax to head has been deprecated quite some time ago, and `-n 1` should be used.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to get the most recent changed file also including any subdirectories you can do it with this little oneliner:

```
find . -type f -exec stat -c '%Y %n' {} \; | sort -nr | awk -v var="1" 'NR==1,NR==var {print $0}' | while read t f; do d=$(date -d @$t "+%b %d %T %Y"); echo "$d -- $f"; done
```

If you want to do the same not for changed files, but for accessed files you simple have to change the

**%Y** parameter from the **stat** command to **%X**. And your command for most recent accessed files looks like this:

```
find . -type f -exec stat -c '%X %n' {} \; | sort -nr | awk -v var="1" 'NR==1,NR==var {print $0}' | while read t f; do d=$(date -d @$t "+%b %d %T %Y"); echo "$d -- $f"; done
```

For both commands you also can change the **var="1"** parameter if you want to list more than just one file.

Comment: find . -type f -exec stat -c '%Y %n' {} \; | sort -nr | head -1 #works too

Answer (score 6):

I personally prefer to use as few not built-in `bash` commands as I can (to reduce the number of expensive fork and exec syscalls). To sort by date the `ls` needed to be called. But using of `head` is not really necessary. I use the following one-liner (works only on systems supporting name pipes):

```
read newest < <(ls -t *.log)
```

or to get the name of the oldest file

```
read oldest < <(ls -rt *.log)
```

(Mind the space between the two '<' marks!)

If the hidden files are also needed -A arg could be added.

I hope this could help.

Comment: You should explain that the filename is stored in $oldest/newest var. But +1 for least amount of forks.

Comment: @squareatom I thought read is fairly well know built-in. But you are right, maybe not. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Assuming you know what a built-in is, you're prob correct. But, I was just think about the OP's question. They asked for a command that would return something. Technically your solution doesn't output anything. So just add "&& echo $newest" or similar to the the end ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Recursively:

```
find $1 -type f -exec stat --format '%Y :%y %n' "{}" \; | sort -nr | cut -d: -f2- | head
```

Answer (score 4):

With only Bash builtins, closely following [BashFAQ/003](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003):

```bash
shopt -s nullglob

for f in * .*; do
    [[ -d $f ]] && continue
    [[ $f -nt "$latest" ]] && latest=$f
done

printf '%s\n' "$latest"
```

Answer (score 3):

using R recursive option .. you may consider this as enhancement for good answers here

```
ls -arRtlh | tail -50
```

Answer (score 2):

try this simple command

```
ls -ltq  <path>  | head -n 1
```

If you want file name - last modified, path = /ab/cd/*.log

If you want  directory name  - last modified, path = /ab/cd/*/

Answer (score 2):

```
ls -t -1 | sed '1q'
```

Will show the last modified item in the folder. Pair with `grep` to find latest entries with keywords

```
ls -t -1 | grep foo | sed '1q'
```

Comment: what is the '1q'? `1` is for the first line equiv to `head -n 1` what is q?

Answer (score 1):

All those ls/tail solutions work perfectly fine for files in *a* directory - ignoring subdirectories.

In order to include all files in your search (recursively), find can be used. gioele suggested sorting the formatted find output. But be careful with whitespaces (his suggestion doesn't work with whitespaces).

This should work with all file names:

```
find $DIR -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | sed -r 's/^[0-9.]+\s+//' | tail -n 1 | xargs -I{} ls -l "{}"
```

This sorts by mtime, see man find:

```
%Ak    File's  last  access  time in the format specified by k, which is either `@' or a directive for the C `strftime' function.  The possible values for k are listed below; some of them might not be available on all systems, due to differences in `strftime' between systems.
       @      seconds since Jan. 1, 1970, 00:00 GMT, with fractional part.
%Ck    File's last status change time in the format specified by k, which is the same as for %A.
%Tk    File's last modification time in the format specified by k, which is the same as for %A.
```

So just replace `%T` with `%C` to sort by ctime.

Comment: You are correct about the white space problem with @gioele suggestion, but you only need to add a hyphen to the -f option to make it a range to fix that: 

`find $DIR -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f 2- | tail -n 1`

Or alternatively, keep all except the first field:

`find $DIR -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f 1 --complement | tail -n 1`

Answer (score 1):

Finding the most current file in every directory according to a pattern, e.g. the sub directories of the working directory that have name ending with "tmp" (case insensitive):

```
find . -iname \*tmp -type d -exec sh -c "ls -lArt {} | tail -n 1" \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you don't care about hidden files that start with a `.`

```
ls -rt | tail -n 1
```

Otherwise

```
ls -Art | tail -n 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -Frt | grep "[^/]$" | tail -n 1
```

Comment: There are other answers that provide the OP's question, and they were posted many years ago. When posting an answer, please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.

Comment: @help-info.de Please don't vote to delete answers that are code-only. They may not be great, but [deletion is for things that are not answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563)

Comment: @Machavity - I hope not to have failed and did a comment only for late answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the last modified folder name within /apps/test directory then you can put below code snippet in a batch script and execute it which will print the name of the last modified folder name.

```
#!/bin/bash -e

export latestModifiedFolderName=$(ls -td /apps/test/*/ | head -n1)

echo Latest modified folder within /apps/test directory is $latestModifiedFolderName
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Fast, unlimited files supported, and special-characters safe:

```
find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\0' \
| sort -zn | tail -zn1 | cut -zc 23- | xargs --null ls -l
```

Replace the final `ls -l` with whatever should process the filename.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep track of changes to files in a directory, you can use [inotify-tools](https://github.com/inotify-tools/inotify-tools):

```
inotifywait -r -e modify,create,delete --format '%w%f' .
```

options: -r recursive, -e EVENTs to monitor, %w watched dir, %f filename in the dir.

Answer (score -1):

I needed to do it too, and I found these commands. these work for me:

If you want last file by its date of creation in folder(access time) :

```
ls -Aru | tail -n 1
```

And if you want last file that has changes in its content (modify time) :

```
ls -Art | tail -n 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Find the file with prefix of `shravan*` and view

```
less $(ls -Art shravan* | tail -n 1)
```