# linux: most recent file in a directory, excluding directories and . files

Tags: linux, bash, unix, directory, find

I would like to find the most recently changed file in a directory, excluding hidden files (the ones that start with .) and also excluding directories.

This question is headed in the right direction, but not exactly what I need:

[Linux: Most recent file in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015678/linux-most-recent-file-in-a-directory)

The key here is to exclude directories...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like the answer there except without -A

```
ls -rt | tail -n 1
```

Look at `man ls` for more info.

To make it exclude directories, we use the -F option to add a "/" to each directory, and then filter for those that don't have the "/":

```
ls -Frt | grep "[^/]$" | tail -n 1
```

Comment: `ls -rt | tail -n 1` doesn't exclude directories.

Comment: Ah okay. Changed appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

This does what you want, excluding directories:

```
stat --printf='%F %Y %n\n' * | sort | grep -v ^directory | head -n 1
```

Answer (score 0):

same one, not very clean but: `ls -c1` + tail if you want => `ls -c1 | tail -1`

```
$ touch a .b
$ ls -c1
a
$ ls -c1a
a
.b
$ touch d
$ ls -c1
d
a
$ ls -c1a
.
d
a
.b
..
$ touch .b
$ ls -c1a
.b
.
d
a
..
```

As you can see, without `a` arg, only visible files are listed.

Comment: it's also showing directories - I'd hoped to exclude those. Am I using your command wrong?

Comment: `ls -cF1 | grep -Ev '/$' | head -1` ?

Answer (score 0):

probably the same as the answer in the other post but with a small difference (excluding directories) -

```
ls --group-directories-first -rt | tail -n 1
```

Comment: also without a '*' symbol at the end of the filename