# How to get the second latest file in a folder in Linux

Tags: linux, shell

Found several posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015678/linux-most-recent-file-in-a-directory) to tell how to find the latest file inside of a folder.

My question is one step forward, how to find the second latest file inside the same folder? The purpose is that I am looking for a way to `diff` the latest log with a previous log so as to know what have been changed. The log was generated in a daily basis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do `diff` of the last (lately modified) two files:

```
ls -t | head -n 2 | xargs diff
```

Answer (score 9):

Building on the linked solutions, you can just make `tail` keep the last *two* files, and then pass the result through `head` to keep the first one of those:

```
ls -Art | tail -n 2 | head -n 1
```

Answer (score 2):

`ls -dt {{your file pattern}} | head -n 2 | tail -n 1`

Will provide second latest file in the pattern you search.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a stat-based solution (tested on linux)

```
for x in ./*; 
do
if [[ -f "$x" ]]; then
  stat --printf="%n %Y\n" "$x"; fi;
done | 
sort -k2,2 -n -r | 
sed -n '2{p;q}'
```

Answer (score -3):

Here's the command returns you latest second file in the folder

```
ls -lt | tail -n 1 | head -n 2
```

enjoy...!