# How to get time since file was last modified in seconds with bash?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I need to get the time in seconds since a file was last modified.  `ls -l` doesn't show it.

Answer (score 110):

There is no simple command to get the time in seconds since a file was modified, but you can compute it from two pieces:

- `date +%s`: the current time in seconds since the Epoch
- `date -r path/to/file +%s`: the last modification time of the specified file in seconds since the Epoch

Use these values, you can apply simple Bash arithmetic:

```
lastModificationSeconds=$(date -r path/to/file +%s)
currentSeconds=$(date +%s)
((elapsedSeconds = currentSeconds - lastModificationSeconds))
```

You could also compute and print the elapsed seconds directly without temporary variables:

```
echo $(($(date +%s) - $(date -r path/to/file +%s)))
```

Comment: And if you want to have it in milliseconds: `$(($(date +'%s%N' -r file.txt)/1000000))`

Comment: If you move the format part as the last argument it works with macs too (at least with sierra). `date -r file.txt +%s` and `echo $(($(date +%s) - $(date -r file.txt +%s)))`

Comment: For folders and subfolders with multiple files use this in conjunction with https://stackoverflow.com/a/23034261/1707015 -- awesome :D

Comment: MacOS supports `date -r` so long as you use it in this order: `date -r file.txt +%s`

Comment: Thanks @Timo, improved the post with that!

Answer (score 12):

In BASH, use this for seconds since last modified:

```
 expr `date +%s` - `stat -c %Y /home/user/my_file`
```

Answer (score 11):

I know the tag is Linux, but the `stat -c` syntax doesn't work for me on OSX. This does work...

```
echo $(( $(date +%s) - $(stat -f%c myfile.txt) ))
```

And as a function to be called with the file name:

```
lastmod(){
     echo "Last modified" $(( $(date +%s) - $(stat -f%c "$1") )) "seconds ago"
}
```

Comment: Maybe that used to work under OS X, but now `-f%c` gives an error. Using `stat -c%Y "$1"` works.

Comment: @BrentFoust  Still works from me with 10.10.5 (and `-c%Y` doesn't). Are you on El Capitan?

Comment: At least on sierra the "linux" way would otherwise work just fine, but it just doesn't like the ordering of the params. It only accepts the format as the last argument. So `date -r file.txt +%s` works for me and it also seems to work for some linuxes, but obviously it's not POSIX so portability is dubious..