# `find` command core dumps in directory with too many files

Tags: linux, find

I have a folder that contains so many files/folders inside it that even basic commands like `du` and  `find` are crashing. I'd like to clean up some old files from it... but obviously I can't do that with the `find` command...

```
# find /opt/graphite/storage/whisper -mtime +30 -type f -delete
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What command or trick can I use to delete files from that folder since `find` isn't working?

Comment: "Aborted" is not a segfault; SIGABRT != SIGSEGV. Still this sounds like a bug in `find`; it shouldn't be crashing even in exceptional situations like this. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413166/when-does-a-process-get-sigabrt-signal-6) leads me to believe it might be running out of memory though, which makes a crash slightly more forgiveable.

Comment: I also think it's running out of memory... Note that `du` suffers the same fate.

Comment: You could write your own C program using `opendir`, `readdir`, `stat` and `unlink`, which is easy to keep within constant memory usage (or at worst, linear in the depth of directory nesting).

Comment: Or, if you don't want to write C, you can try some Perl: [Perl to the Rescue: Case Study of Deleting a Large Directory](http://blogs.perl.org/users/randal_l_schwartz/2011/03/perl-to-the-rescue-case-study-of-deleting-a-large-directory.html)

Comment: Or in python:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48393588/1930462  (search for "readdir" there).  Might go this route if no-one finds a bash command that can do it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to go is using a simple for-loop: the problem is that `find` loads all found information in memory, and only once this is done, it starts deleting.
However, a loop can solve this:

```
for f in $(ls -a)
do 
  if <check_last_modification_date>($f)
  then rm -r $f
  fi
done
```

Concerning the last modification date check, there are plenty of ways to do this, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463334/how-to-get-time-since-file-was-last-modified-in-seconds-with-bash/19464264).

Answer (score 0):

For `find` command using the `-exec` option worked for me to delete the files.

```
# find /opt/graphite/storage/whisper -mtime +30 -type f -exec rm -f {} \;
```