# Wait google chrome all downloads finshed with shell command

Tags: bash, shell, google-chrome, browser, keyboard-maestro

Every day I need to download a lot of pictures in a row through the Google plugin, concentrated in a few minutes. So I want to have a script that can clearly let me know that the download tasks currently in progress by Google have all been completed, so that I can easily go to the next processing flow.

My main reference materials are:

[1. Keyboard Maestro with lsof command](http://www.macinations.com/2021/04/05/monitoring-the-downloads-folder-with-keyboard-maestro/)

[2.shell command with stat](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91207/wait-for-multiple-files-to-be-finished-downloading)

### Method 1 Failed

According to the first scenario, I have used the command

```bash
lsof -c /Chrome/i  | grep "/Users/ifxl/Downloads/tmp_images/ref"
lsof -c /Chrome/i  | grep "/Users/ifxl/Downloads/"
```

However, this judgment is very unstable, and it is often judged too early that the download has been completed, but in fact it is not.

---

### Method 2 Error

```
#! /bin/bash
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

dir="/Users/ifxl/Downloads/tmp_images/ref/"
# check whether $dir exists
#test -d "${dir}" || exit 1

last=0
current=1

while [ "$last" != "$current" ]; do
   last=$current
   current=$(find "${dir}" -exec stat -c "%Y" \{\} \; |
      sort -n | tail -1)
   sleep 10
done
echo "directory is now stable..."
```

This method will pop up an error reminder:

```
stat: illegal option -- c
usage: stat [-FLnq] [-f format | -l | -r | -s | -x] [-t timefmt] [file ...]
```

Is there a very elegant way to determine that all downloads have been completed in Google Chrome.

Or, is there a very ingenious way to achieve a very accurate judgment?

Comment: what do you get for `stat --version`?

Comment: `stat --version                          
stat: illegal option -- -
usage: stat [-FLnq] [-f format | -l | -r | -s | -x] [-t timefmt] [file ...]`

Comment: echo $(( $(date +%s) - $(stat -f%c $(ls -t | head -n1)) ))

Comment: maybe  time will be the best choice ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463334/how-to-get-time-since-file-was-last-modified-in-seconds-with-bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# into the parent folder which download files exsit.
cd /Users/ifxl/Downloads/tmp_images/

# count how many seconds the final folder exsit
echo $(( $(date +%s) - $(/usr/bin/stat -f%c  ref) ))
```

[image]

Comment: with Keyboard Maestro this macro works so well

Answer (score 0):

You can write a browser extension that monitors downloads and communicate with it via web socket.

Comment: thks. 
I only know a bit of shell , MY code skills so poor