# Bash script to find and display oldest file

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm trying to write a script that will display the name of oldest file within the directory that the script is executed from.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
for arg in $*
do
 oldest=$1
 if [[ $arg -ot $oldest ]]
 then
  oldest=$arg
 fi
done

echo "Oldest file: $oldest"
```

I'm not sure how to increment to the next file to check if it is older

for example:

```
oldest=$2
oldest=$3
etc..
```

trying to run this script in the bash shell given the following args:

```
myScript `ls -a`
```

I get a result of:

```
Oldest File: .
```

Comment: `for arg in $*` is buggy -- try it with arguments that contain whitespace or quoted wildcards to see why. `for arg in "$@"` or just `for arg` (as default behavior is to iterate over `"$@"`) is the correct alternative. Of course, all of those are assuming that you're iterating over command-line arguments, not files.

Comment: ...to iterate over files, it's `for arg in *`, perhaps with a `[ -d "$arg" ] && continue` just inside the loop to skip directories.

Answer (score 8):

The `ls` program has an option to sort on time and you can just grab the last file from that output::

```
# These are both "wun", not "ell".
#             v          v
oldest="$(ls -1t | tail -1)"
```

If you want to avoid directories, you can strip them out beforehand:

```
# This one's an "ell", this is still a "wun".
              v                         v
oldest="$(ls -lt | grep -v '^d' | tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}')"
```

I wouldn't normally advocate parsing `ls` output but it's fine for quick and dirty jobs, and if you understand its limitations.

---

If you want a script that will work even for crazies who insist on putting control characters in their file names :-) then [this page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) has some better options, including:

```
unset -v oldest
for file in "$dir"/*; do
    [[ -z $oldest || $file -ot $oldest ]] && oldest=$file
done
```

Though I'd suggest following that link to understand *why* `ls` parsing is considered a bad idea generally (and hence why it can be useful in limited circumstances such as when you can *guarantee* all your files are of the `YYYY-MM-DD.log` variety for example). There's a font of useful information over there.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for a description of why this is a bad idea, and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003 for a best-practices alternative.

Comment: Thx, @Charles, added that link and one option on it, which seems to satisfy the specific requirements here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function to find oldest file/directory in any directory:

```
oldest() { 
   oldf=
   for f in *; do
      # not a file, ignore
      [[ ! -f "$f" ]] && continue
      # find oldest entry
      [[ -z "$oldf" ]] && oldf="$f" || [[ "$f" -ot "$oldf" ]] && oldf="$f"
   done
   printf '%s\n' "$oldf"
}
```

And call it in any directory as:

```
oldest
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `find` command:
`find -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort | head -1`

Comment: Revise that to `{ IFS= read -r -d' ' time; IFS= read -r -d '' name; } < <(find -type f -printf '%T+ %p\0' | sort -z)` and you work with all possible filenames, including ones with newlines (which your current code doesn't handle). Requires GNU sort, of course, but since you're already depending on a GNU extension to find...

Answer (score 2):

The following oneliner finds the oldest file in the whole subtree and reports it using the long format and relative full path. What else could you ever need?

```
ls -ltd $(find . -type f) | tail -1
```

Comment: This one fails if the number of files is large, because the argument list is too long.