# Select and upload videos from shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to upload videos to YouTube via a Bash shell script. I want to run this script for a specific folder where, when the script is run it, should select only the latest file inside this folder.

I have written the code to upload from shell, but need help to select the latest file automatically.

```
#!/bin/sh

# youtube-upload


read -p 'Title (default filename): ' TITLE # defaults to filename
read -p 'Privacy (public | unlisted | private): ' PRIVACY # defaults to private
read -p 'Video link:'  LINK


PRIVACY="--privacy ${PRIVACY:-private}"
CREDENTIALS='--client-secrets=/home/thanos/Desktop/client_secrets.json'




VIDEO_ID="$(youtube-upload --title="$TITLE" $PRIVACY $CREDENTIALS $LINK)"

VIDEO_LINK="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$VIDEO_ID"
echo "$VIDEO_LINK" > ~/Desktop/Upload-Links/"$(date +%d%m%Y-%H%M%S).txt"


read -p "Upload Complete.  Press any key to continue."`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux: Most recent file in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015678/linux-most-recent-file-in-a-directory)

Comment: See also [BashFAQ/003](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) and [BashFAQ/099](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/099): "How can I sort or compare files based on some metadata attribute (newest / oldest modification time, size, etc)?" and "How can I get the newest (or oldest) file from a directory?"

Comment: use `stat -c "%Y %n" *`

Answer (score 1):

This would give you the latest modified file:

```
LAST_MOD_FILE="$(ls -1t | head -1)"
echo $LAST_MOD_FILE
```

Comment: Please dont mind me asking as im just a beginner, in the code that you have given me, where is it that i would be mentioning the folder path

Comment: It would be in the `ls` command, as in `ls -1t /path/to/your-folder/ | head -1`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help... I'm very close in making it possible.  Will update  wen i do it

Comment: Hi this.lau, i have tried the code you had provided and it worked. the question i have is, im trying to implement the same functionality in node.js. what are my options?

Comment: Hi @TH4N0s, you might want to create a new question about this to get more answers. I suspect you'll simply have to call [fs.readdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) and search for the most recent file in there.