# Using tac on most recent log file out of several log files in a directory

Tags: tac

I have several log files in a directory that we’ll call `path/to/directory` that are in the following format after long listing in Red Hat Enterprise 6:

```
-rw-r——-. 1 root root 17096 Sep 30 11:00 logfile_YYYYDDMM_HHMMSS.log
```

There are several of these log files that are generated everyday. I need to automatically `tac` the most recently-modified file without typing the exact name of the log file. For example, I’d like to do:

```
tac /path/to/directory/logile*.log | grep -m 1 keyword
```

And have it automatically `tac` the most recently modified file and `grep` the keyword in the reverse direction from the end of the log file so it runs quicker. Is this possible?

The problem I’m running into is that there is always more than one log file in the `/path/to/directory` and I can’t get Linux to automatically `tac` the most recently modified file as of yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I’ve tried:

```
tac /path/to/directory/logfile_$(date +%Y%m%d)*.log
```

which will `tac` a file created on the present date but the part that I’m having trouble with is using `tac` on the newest file (by YYYYMMDD AND HHMMSS) because multiple files can be generated on the same date but only one of them can be the most current and the most current log file is the only one I care about. I can’t use a symbolic link either.. Limitations, sigh.

Comment: Not an answer, but here are some examples for getting hold of the most recent filename: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015678/linux-most-recent-file-in-a-directory (`ls -ABt1 | head -n1` seems like the best option for what you're trying to do). Then I guess you can use `awk` or something like that to call `tak` and `grep`?

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave, note that it's usually a [bad idea to parse ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)...

Comment: Thank you so much. I believe the guidance you provided is the answer to the problem I was having. It works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you seem to be expressing in your question isn't so much about `tac`, but rather .. how to select the most recent of a set of predictably named files in a directory.

If your filenames really are in the format `logfile_YYYYDDMM_HHMMSS.log`, then they will sort lexically without the need for an innate understanding of dates. Thus, if your shell is bash, you might:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for x in /path/to/logfile_*.log; do
  [[ "$x" > "$file" ]] && file="$x"
done
```

The `nullglob` option tells bash to expand a glob matching no files as a null rather than as a literal string. Following the code above, you might want to test for the existence of `$hit` before feeding it to `tac`.