# Remove patterns using awk or sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm using

> ls -ltr

to grab a directory listing and I'd like to grab the last line, but, only the file name.

so output of

> ls -ltr

shows something like this:

> -rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   10735 Jan  7 12:46 file_I_want.csv

How would I grab just the file name so that I can make a variable out of it?

Much appreciated.

Comment: You are expected to demonstrate some effort - at the very least, show us what you searched for and what you found. But [parsing `ls` is a flawed idea](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs); what are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015678/get-most-recent-file-in-a-directory-on-linux

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
command ls -t | sed q
```

It's a rare use case where I pipe `ls`.

`command` is there to avoid using an alias.

Parsing `ls` in other use cases should be avoided.

`sed q` is a little hack to display the first item.

This solution works also with filenames with whitespaces

Comment: This is perfect. Simple to also just remove "l" from ls and all is good. Thanks for your solution!