# how to find a last updated file with the prefix name in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

How can I find a last updated file with the specific prefix in bash?

For example, I have three files, and I just want to see a file that has "ABC" and where the last Last_updatedDateTime desc.

```
fileName Last_UpdatedDateTime

abc123   7/8/2020 10:34am 
abc456   7/6/2020 10:34am 
def123   7/8/2020 10:34am
```

Comment: Note that it's case sensitive so `ABC` will not match any of those files.

Comment: Very very closely related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/1015678/3266847

Comment: @BenjaminW. Indeed related. I find listing it in reverse order to grab the last entry instead of grabbing the first is a bit odd though. If `head -1` exits at least `ls` gets the chance to quit early (because writing on `stdout` fails). With `tail -1` it _must_ run through the whole list.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm not saying the highest voted answers on there are good, just that the question is almost identical ;)

Comment: See also [BashFAQ/003](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003)

Comment: What is `Last_UpdatedDateTime`, by the way? Do you have these files, or a table with filenames and these datetime strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list files sorted in the order they were modified with `ls -t`:

```
 -t     sort by modification time, newest first
```

You can use globbing (`abc*`) to match all files starting with `abc`.

Since you will get more than one match and only want the newest (that is first):

```
head -1
```

Combined:

```
ls -t abc* | head -1
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are a lot of these files scattered across a variety of directories, `find` mind be better.

```
find -name abc\* -printf "%T@ %f\n" |sort -nr|sed 's/^.* //; q;'
```

Breaking that out -

```
find -name 'abc*' -printf "%T@ %f\n" |
```

`find` has a ton of options. This is the simplest case, assuming the current directory  as the root of the search. You can add a lot of refinements, or just give `/` to search the whole system.

`-name 'abc*'` picks just the filenames you want. Quote it to protect any globs, but you can use normal globbing rules. `-iname` makes the search case-insensitive.

`-printf` defines the output. `%f` prints the filename, but you want it ordered on the date, so print that first for sorting so the filename itself doesn't change the order. `%T` accepts another character to define the date format - `@` is the unix epoch, seconds since 00:00:00 01/01/1970, so it is easy to sort numerically. On my git bash emulation it returns fractions as well, so it's great granularity.

```
$: find -name abc\* -printf "%T@ %f\n"
1594219755.7741618000 abc123
1594219775.5162510000 abc321
1594219734.0162554000 abc456
```

`find` may not return them in the order you want, though, so -

```
sort -nr |
```

`-n` makes it a numeric sort. `-r` sorts in reverse order, so that the latest file will pop out first and you can ignore everything after that.

```
sed 's/^.* //; q;'
```

Since the first record is the one we want, `sed` can just use `s/^.* //;` to strip off everything up to the space, which we know will be the timestamp numbers since we controlled the output explicitly. That leaves only the filename. `q` explicitly quits after the `s///` scrubs the record, so `sed` spits out the filename and stops without reading the rest, which prevents the need for another process (`head -1`) in the pipeline.