# Trying to diff two files with generated paths - no such file or directory - but files exist

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to diff two files in the same directory in a bash script. To get the full paths of these two files (I need this because the script isn't running the same directory), I did:

```
pathToOld=$(ls -Art /dir/path/here | grep somestring | tail -n2 | head -n1)
pathToOld="/dir/path/here/${pathToOld}"
```

and

```sh
pathToNew=$(ls -Art /dir/path/here | grep somestring | tail -n 1)
pathToNew="/dir/path/here/${pathToNew}"
```

I was able to figure out the above from the following links: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015678/get-most-recent-file-in-a-directory-on-linux), [link2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190065/how-to-read-only-the-second-last-line-of-a-file), [link3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190065/how-to-read-only-the-second-last-line-of-a-file)

If I echo these path in the .sh script, it comes out correctly, like:

```
>echo "${pathToOld}"
/dir/path/here/oldFile
```

But when I try to diff the files like so:

```
diff pathToOld pathToNew
```

It tells me:

```
diff: pathToOld: No such file or directory
diff: pathToNew: No such file or directory
```

How do I make this work?
Btw, I have also tried to pipe `sed -z 's/\n/ /g'` (inspired by this) to both lines but that hasn't helped.

Comment: Variable are used with an `$`, `diff` now sees it as a file path, which doesnt exist

Comment: Use `diff "$pathToOld" "$pathToNew"`

Comment: `diff pathToOld pathToNew` - how should the bash know that you want to use variables?

Comment: That was so silly - thank you so much!